# How to Parse Timestamps from Conversation Index value?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, message

I tried to Extract the **Header Date** and **ChildBlock**  Timestamps from **Conversation index** value with reference to https://www.meridiandiscovery.com/how-to/e-mail-conversation-index-metadata-computer-forensics/

Example Conversation index:

AQHXpuHfZBAfN0osC0iudIJ19I04SA==
AQHXpuHfZBAfN0osC0iudIJ19I04SKued4wAgAAALkU=

But I'm not getting the Header date and ChildBlock Timestamps Value as Expected (Timestamps doesn't match with actual and differs a lot ).

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Does it match what you see in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button, select the `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX` property, see the parsed value on the Symbol edit box)?

Comment: No, The parsed value of PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX in Outlook Spy differs from actual data (Time stamps Differs) and also differs the from the parsed hex values of timestamps using above reference Link.